# cant convert a find all over many records to paginatein cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant convert this find all to a paginate statement. The find all works fine as below. Then I converted this to paginate with error

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Lesson.id' in 'on clause'. Not sure what to do as I have done paginate before without issues.

```
  $lessons = $this->find('all', array(
      //     'conditions' =>$default_array,
         'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'lessons_students',
                'alias' => 'LessonStudents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'LessonStudents.student_id' => $studentId,
                    'LessonStudents.lesson_id = Lesson.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'group' => 'Lesson.id',
        'order' => array('Lesson.lesson_date' => 'asc'),
        ));


   $this->Paginator->settings = array(   
        // 'conditions' =>$default_array,
         'joins' => array(
             array('table' => 'lessons_students',
                'alias' => 'LessonStudents',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'LessonStudents.student_id' => $id,
                    'LessonStudents.lesson_id = Lesson.id'
                 )
              )
             ),
             'group' => 'Lesson.id',
        'order' => array('Lesson.lesson_date' => 'asc'),
             );

                $lessons =$this->Paginator->paginate('Student'); //also tried lesson
```

Comment: For the context of `$this` what controller is this code in? And what is the model relation to Lesson?

Comment: in Student controller and student/lesson has HABTM relationship

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `'recursive'` option in the Paginator settings to a value, for example 2?

Comment: recursive setting this has no effect with any value. Might be quicker doing an example if this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the join should cal  a variable which does work. I solved it this way